# Whats the difference between double.infinity and MediaQuery?

Tags: dart, flutter

To occupy the whole width or height , I use `double.infinity`, but going through some of the flutter samples, I have noticed many people use `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width` or `height`. I went through the docs but there are no differences mentioned between this two or when to use which one as both allow same feature. Are they specific to particular widgets?

Comment: @pskink whichever widgets have width and height property

Comment: @pskink but i canuse MediaQuery as well with Containers

Comment: @pskink yeah i get that, but whats the difference between two, when to use what and are there any performance caveats related to them

Comment: @pskink please read the question heading again

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The difference can be summarized into:

- I want to be as big as my parent allows (double.infinity)
- I want to be as big as the screen (MediaQuery).

Usually, you'll want to use `double.infinity`, but it's not always possible.

Some Widgets allow their children to be as big as they want to be (`Column`, `ListView`, `OverflowBox`...). In that situation using `double.infinity` creates a paradox:

- The parent allows any size
- The child wants the biggest size allowed by the parent

---

Using `MediaQuery` in these situations is bad though. You will rarely want to do that unless you're creating a widget similar to `Scaffold`.

That's where widgets such as `IntrinsincHeight` comes in handy. These widgets are able to solve the paradox, and therefore have a valid layout.

Comment: You can use `double.infinity` in child of an `OverflowBox` widget.

Comment: I read the exact same answer word for word here: https://flutteragency.com/difference-between-double-infinity-and-mediaquery/

Answer (score 2):

**MediaQuery** occupies the space as per the screen size whereas **double.infinity** occupies the space as parent size. It could be matched with *match-parent* in Android.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).